# v8 Persistent SetWeak crashed with NEAR_DEATH

Tags: javascript, c++, memory-leaks, v8

my code:

```
struct WeakData {
    context* c;
    std::vector<UniquePersistent<Object>>::iterator i;
};

void WeakPtrCallback(const v8::WeakCallbackData<v8::Object, WeakData>& data) {
    printf("weak callback");
    fflush(stdout);
    // crashes always after exit from this callback
}

Local<Object> wrapDocumentSelection(Isolate* isolate, cDocumentSelection* selection) {
    EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    auto ctx = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
    Context::Scope context_scope(ctx);

    Local<External> contextWrap = Local<External>::Cast(
            Handle<Object>::Cast(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global()->GetPrototype())->GetInternalField(0));
    context* c = static_cast<context*>(contextWrap->Value());

    Local<ObjectTemplate> documentSelectionTemplate = Local<ObjectTemplate>::New(isolate, c->documentSelectionTemplate);

    Local<Object> jsSelection = documentSelectionTemplate->NewInstance(ctx).ToLocalChecked();
    jsSelection->SetInternalField(0, External::New(isolate, selection));
    jsSelection->Set(ctx, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "length"), Integer::New(isolate, selection->Length));

    c->trackingObjects.push_back(UniquePersistent<Object>(isolate, jsSelection));
    auto &p = c->trackingObjects.back();
    auto it = c->trackingObjects.end();
    it--;

    WeakData* wd = new WeakData;
    wd->c = c;
    wd->i = it;

    p.Reset(isolate, jsSelection);
    p.SetWeak<WeakData>(NULL, WeakPtrCallback);
    isolate->AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(1024);

    return handle_scope.Escape(jsSelection);
}
```

in context I'm keeping vector of all persistent handles while
In WeakPtrCallback I will need to clean up some external allocated resources

v8 error:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../src/global-handles.cc, line 325
# Check failed: state() != NEAR_DEATH.
#
```

regarding https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-v0-12-c-apis-breaking/
I do not need to perform any v8 related cleanup in the callback

> The persistent's storage cell is automatically disposed.  Keep a reference to the original v8::Persistent if you want to revive it with .ClearWeak().

I also tried to use Persistent and `Persistent<Value, CopyablePersistentTraits<Value>>` - same error...
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my C++ is not good enough it seems
I tracked down the problem to issue with the vector, for some reason it could not properly remove required element, I guess iterator is index-bound, so deleting some previous element spoils all further going iterator references...

Switching to std::map with constantly incrementing counter as a key completely solved the issue

Comment: I'm not sure how that solved your problem, but the actual problem most likely was that you weren't cleaning up your global before your setweak callback finished, which would lead to a leak, so there's an assert to make sure all the globals for the object that is being garbage collected are taken care of.   You want to call Reset on your global in the setweak callback to properly release it.

Comment: @xaxxon this is right. The thing was I also tried/had another version where used std::vector to store Persistent handles, and obviously you can't just erase element from a vector without invalidating all further going references to this vector... So yep, it failed to reset correct PersistentHandle and assert was triggered.